# Nextjs App Router OG Image not showing up when deployed

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, next.js13

I have a Nextjs project running app router. In the app directory, i have a file called `opengraph-image.png`. I expect this to be the OG Image of the landing page, however when i deploy and check the OG image nothing shows up. This is my layout.js code. I had to move the previous code into RootLayout since it was dealing with a mix of client / server side code. Anyone know why the OG image does not show up?

```
import RootLayout from "@/components/root/root-layout";
import { Metadata } from "next";

const title = "Test Title";
const description = "Test Description";

export const metadata = {
  title,
  description,
  openGraph: {
    title,
    description,
  },
  twitter: {
    title,
    description,
    card: "summary_large_image",
    creator: "@me",
  },
  metadataBase: new URL("https://urlgoeshere"),
  themeColor: "#ffffff",
};

export default function OGLayout({ children }) {
  return <RootLayout children={children} />;
}
```

I tried hardcoding an image instead of dynamically generating it and it still wont show

Answer (score 0):

`next 14.0.4` and the following worked!

```
import ogImage from './opengraph-image.jpg'
...
export const metadata = {
  ...
  metadataBase: new URL("https://yourWebUrl.com"),
  openGraph: {
    ...
    images: [
      {
        url: ogImage.src,
        width: ogImage.width,
        height: ogImage.height
      },
    ],
  },
  twitter: {
    images: [
      {
        url: ogImage.src,
        width: ogImage.width,
        height: ogImage.height
      },
    ]
  },
}
```